# Applying the Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on the complex plane that maps the unit disc $\mathbb D$ into itself, such that $f(0)=0$. Suppose also that $f$ is not polynomial. Can we conclude from Schwarz Lemma that $f^n(\mathbb D)\to 0$? That is, repeated iterations of $f$ shrink the disk to 0?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{D}$ the closed or open?

Comment: the question is ambiguous; for example if $f(z)=z\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$ then $f^{n}(\mathbb D)=\mathbb D$ for all $n$ and morever $f^{n}$ is a $2^n$ to $1$ surjective map of the open disc to itself; if you ask the trajectory of an individual element, that's a different question

Comment: @Conrad Your $f$ is not holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ though.

Comment: @Caffeine that is a good point but one can take an entire function that maps the unit disc into itself, is not a polynomial and for which $f(1)=1, f(0)=0$ (for example $f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{e-1}$ as $|e^z-1|=|\sum_{n \ge 1}z^n/n!| \le e-1, |z| \le 1$) and then clearly $f^n(\mathbb D)$ contains a neighborhood of $1$ (intersected with the open unit disc and depending on $n$ of course) for all $n$